# Mongoose schema for arrays of refs with role

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, role, refs

I'm very new to the NoSQL way of doing things so please excuse me if I'm just thinking about this completely wrong (I feel like I am).

My application has Users and Organizations, and the Users must have and belong to those Organizations with a role of member or owner.

Currently in my schema for my Users I have:

> > orgs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Org' }]

and in my schema for my Organizations I have:

> > members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]

but I would also like to attach a role of member or owner to this.

Is this something I should put in the actual reference somehow like:

> > members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', role: String }]

or should the role be elsewhere in the schema?  What is the proper way to handle this or is there a different way to schematize this that is more appropriate?

And once I have the schema set up for this properly, it would be helpful to have an example of how to create a few users/orgs with this roled ref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a small change to what you have there. I store messages in an app the same way (text and sender).

Here's what you could do:

```
members: [{
    role: { 
      type: String
    },
    user: { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }],
```

Then when you want to add a member or members to an organization (assume you have already created an organization and a user separately):

```
function addNewMember(org_id, user_id, role) {   
    var member = {role: role, user: user_id};
    Organization.findByIdAndUpdate(org_id, {"$push": {"members":member}}, function(err,org) {
               ...
             });)  
// you can use the $each clause to add a whole array of members at the same time too
// like so:
// {"$push": {"members": 
//              {
//              "$each": [memberarray]
//              }}}

}
```

And when you want to find an organization including it's members, you could do:

```
    Organization.findById(org_id) 
        .populate('members.user')
        .exec(callbackfunction);
```

Think carefully if you do absolutely need to duplicate the Organization -> member relationship for each member too as Member -> organizations.  If this is indeed important, after successfully adding the user to the organization, in the callback you can do a second query to update the user's orgs field just like above.